# Force a one-dimensional array into a constant in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function, array

I have a condition in an Excel IF-statement as follows:

```
INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(ME3),MATCH("PremiumWaiver",$1:$1,0)))=1
```

where

```
INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(ME3),MATCH("PremiumWaiver",$1:$1,0)))
```

eveluates to `{1}`.

Is there any way I can force this `{1}` into `1` such that

```
INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(ME3),MATCH("PremiumWaiver",$1:$1,0)))=1
```

will return `TRUE`?

Comment: It shouldn't be returning an array.  Is {1} what you're seeing in a cell if you just copy your partial formula somewhere else?  Is it possibly a rounding issue if not all decimals are displayed?  Does it result in true if you use the actual cell address instead of using indirect and address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `ROW` function that returns an array, you could replace by `ROWS`, e.g.

`=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROWS($ME$1:ME3),MATCH("PremiumWaiver",$1:$1,0)))`

or you can use a function like SUM around ROW

`=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(SUM(ROW(ME3)),MATCH("PremiumWaiver",$1:$1,0)))`

although I'm not really sure you need INDIRECT and ADDRESS at all, you can use INDEX or OFFSET, e.g.

`=OFFSET($A$1,SUM(ROW(ME3))-1,MATCH("PremiumWaiver",$1:$1,0)-1)`

Answer (score 0):

if `{1}` means an array, then try the `INDEX` function:

`INDEX(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(ME3),MATCH("PremiumWaiver",$1:$1,0))),1)=1`